# Why is my two javascript codes not running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two different scripts on one page and when I call them both, one of them doesn't work. If I delete one then the one left works. Why aren't they both working? Here is what I have in the head of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var nice = $("html").niceScroll();
        $("#outer").html($("#outer").html());
        $(".overflow").niceScroll({
            cursorborder: "",
            cursorcolor: "#333333",
            boxzoom: false,
            cursorwidth: "5px"
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabslider/javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabslider/javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabslider/javascripts/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
    });
</script>
```

[Posted code on PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/MwNTNhXV](http://pastebin.com/MwNTNhXV)

Comment: can you show us the HTML as well?

Comment: How do you error test it? Have you tried removing one command at a time, and not just a whole line at a time?

Comment: Maybe because you are importing jQuery after the first script.

Comment: Why do you have 3 versions of jQuery linked?  Also, what does your console say?

Comment: @imtuned, please always add code in your question (even if you share a link jsfiddle or pastebin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your script should look like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabslider/javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabslider/javascripts/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nice = $("html").niceScroll(); 
    $("#outer").html($("#outer").html());
    $(".overflow").niceScroll({cursorborder:"",cursorcolor:"#333333",boxzoom:false,cursorwidth:"5px"}); 
    $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
});
</script>
```

the issue is that you're loading 3 jQuery versions and the order of other script is not right